# How to search for string in any order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, search

I have a .js file with an array of strings inside. Let's say one of my arrays has the string "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog". I can search "The quick brown fox" and it will display the string in my array which has that value. But if I were to search "The quick fox jumps lazy dog", it will not display the line. My search needs to be in the same order as the string appears in the array or it will not work. How can I search in my array in such a way that it will display matching entries instead of exact entries?

Here is my code:

```
//App.js
import { useState } from "react";
import { Data } from "./data";
import "./App.css";
import Table from "./Table";

 function App() {
   const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
   const keys = [""];

   const search = (data) => {
     return data.filter((item) =>
       keys.some((key) => item.toLowerCase().includes(query))
     );
   };

 return (
   <div className="app">
     <h1>Search Something</h1>
     {/* <Home /> */}
     
     <div className="searchBoxes">
       <input
         className="search"
         placeholder="Search Array..."
         onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value.toLowerCase())}
       />
       </div>

     {<Table data={search(Data)} />}
   </div>
 );
 }

 export default App;
```

```
//data.js
export const Data = ["The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC"]
```

```
//Table.jsx
const Table = ({ data }) => {
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((item, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{item}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  };
  
  export default Table;
```

I tried using different array functions like .map() but did not get the desired result.

Comment: Hi @JohnA, you should look for string search algorithms

Comment: Hi @lissettdm do you have any suggestions for a search algorithm that will work with ReactJS and provide me my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong order of how to search within the `data` array.

```
const search = (data) => {
    queryWords = query.split(' ').filter(queryWord => queryWord.length > 0)
    return data.filter(dataEntry => queryWords.every(queryWord => dataEntry.toLowerCase().split(' ').includes(queryWord) || dataEntry.toLowerCase().includes(queryWord)))
   };
```

`queryWords` contain every word in the search query, e.g. if you were searching for *the brown dog*, then:

```
query='the brown dog'
```

Now you split by `' '`, which gives you the array

```
queryWords = ['the', 'brown', 'dog']
```

You need to filter this so it doesn't contain any empty strings. This is where `filter(queryWord => queryWord.length > 0)` comes into play.

What you need to do know is filter each `dataEntry` of your `data` array: You are looking for entries that contain **`every`** word from your search query OR the whole sentence (notice the `||` operator and `dataEntry.toLowerCase().includes(queryWord)` is basically like your initial idea.